# Custom parent element's style not applied to child

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-html

I created a custom Polymer Dart element that extends another custom element. The parent element has a style defined containing a :host selector. When adding the parent element to the DOM, the style is applied as expected.

When extending the parent element and adding the child element to the DOM, the style defined for the parent element is not always applied. When testing the following code in Dartium v36.0.1985.97 (280598) or Chrome v35.0.1916.153, both elements are displayed with the proper style applied. When tested in Firefox 28.0 and Chrome v34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972), only the parent element has the style applied.

**pubspec.yaml:**

```dart
name: myapp
dependencies:
  polymer: ">=0.12.0-dev <0.12.0"
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
```

**index.html:**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>index</title>
    <!-- <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
         not necessary anymore with Polymer >= 0.14.0 -->
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- parent element -->
<polymer-element name="my-parent">
    <template>
        <style>
        :host {
            background:red;
        }
        </style>
        <content></content>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
<script type="application/dart" src="my-child.dart"></script>

<!-- child element -->
<polymer-element name="my-child" extends="my-parent">
</polymer-element>
<script type="application/dart" src="my-parent.dart"></script>

<p><my-parent>RED? (parent elment)</my-parent>
<p><my-child>RED? (child element)</my-child>

<script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output in Dartium v36.0.1985.97 (280598) and Chrome v35.0.1916.153:**

(I need 10 reputation to post images, so please see result at: http://s30.postimg.org/8j3x3l2m9/Dartium.png)

**Output in Firefox 28.0 and Chrome v34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972)**

(Result at: http://s1.postimg.org/f210lwhj3/Firefox.png)

I am inclined to classify this as a bug but would appreciate feedback from the SO community to see if there is anything wrong with my implementation. Are there any additional steps required to ensure the styled defined in the parent element is also applied when creating a child element?

Comment: This is probably a bug you should report it at dartbug.com. What Dart and what Polymer version are you using?

Comment: I found this open issues about similar problems https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18171, https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19841

Comment: This was reproduced using Polymer Dart 0.12.0-dev (Jul 11, 2014) and Dart SDK version 1.5.3.

Comment: Thanks Günter. I added the information from this post to the referenced bug report. That bug report seems similar enough so let's continue the discussion at https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19841.

Comment: Actually you added it to 18171 not 19841 ;-) I guess they have to forward it to the Blink or the Polymer (JS) team.

Comment: Thanks, good catch! The two Dart bug reports appear to be duplicates so I'll keep the comment in 18171.